# Traefik: Let'sEncrypt onHostRule without [acme.domains]?

Tags: docker, traefik

Is it possible to use Traefik's **onHostRule: true** option also for 2nd-level domains (not sub-domains)?

I have a container configured with the following label:

```
labels:
   - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.mydomain.com"
```

I'd like traffic to automatically pull a HTTPS certificate from LetsEncrypt without me needed to edit the Traefik.toml file and adding the following lines:

```
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "api.mydomain.com"
```

I read that Traefik can auto-generate SSL certs for sub-domains of domains which are listed in [[acme.domains]] but I'd like to have the flexibility to attach a container with any domain without the hassle of editing Traefik.toml and restarting Traefik.

Answer (score 1):

**`[[acme.domains]]` is not related to `onHostRule`.**

The certificates for the domains defined in `[[acme.domains]]` are obtained at the start of Traefik.

`onHostRule` allow to obtain certificates based on `Host:` rule define on container, these certificates are obtained when a container is detected by Traefik.

Traefik can get certificates, whether it's a subdomain or a domain.

- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#onhostrule
- https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/acme/#domains

Comment: Yes I can actually confirm that my second domain was properly obtained just based on the Host: rule. On the other hand, the first Host: rule didn't seem to work unless  the [[acme.domains]] was put in place. Is it possible that the [[acme.domains]] tag is simply required to be present?

Comment: no because `[[acme.domains]]` is not related to `onHostRule`.